# In Rails 5 having issues with Ransack query and my Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, ransack

I have a controller, **Players::SearchesController**

```
class Players::SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @q = Player.ransack(search_params[:q])
    @players = Player.none
  end

  def create
    # This executes when I initiate a ransack search
  end

  private

    def search_params
      params.permit(:utf8, :commit, :search_type, :current_user_id, :q)
      params.require(:q).permit!
    end

end
```

I'm using it without any model that is associated with it.  I'm trying to use it with ransack but I keep getting the following error in my terminal when running a search.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the "q" parameter to be permitted.

```
(byebug) search_params
Unpermitted parameter: :q
<ActionController::Parameters {"position_id_in"=>["", "5"], "draft_year_in"=>["", "2019"], "measurable_summary_height_gteq"=>"5080", "measurable_summary_height_lteq"=>"5080", "measurable_summary_weight_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_weight_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_speed_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_speed_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_ten_yard_dash_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_ten_yard_dash_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_test_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_test_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_hand_span_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_hand_span_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_arm_length_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_arm_length_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_vertical_jump_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_vertical_jump_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_bench_reps_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_bench_reps_lteq"=>""} permitted: true>
```

Here is what consists of my `params` object as well...

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=><ActionController::Parameters {"position_id_in"=>["", "5"], "draft_year_in"=>["", "2019"], "measurable_summary_height_gteq"=>"5080", "measurable_summary_height_lteq"=>"5080", "measurable_summary_weight_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_weight_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_speed_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_speed_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_ten_yard_dash_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_ten_yard_dash_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_test_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_test_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_hand_span_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_hand_span_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_arm_length_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_arm_length_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_vertical_jump_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_vertical_jump_lteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_bench_reps_gteq"=>"", "measurable_summary_bench_reps_lteq"=>""} permitted: true>, "search_type"=>"measurables", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"players/searches", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your search params like this

```
def search_params
  params.permit(:utf8, :commit, :search_type, :current_user_id, q: [:position_id_in, :draft_year_in.......])
  params.require(:q).permit!
end
```

and add all the other params you want to permit inside q: [] like in the example